# simple css fade transition not working through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When I use jQuery to change the opacity to 0 and to 1, it doesn't work. It works whens theres no position absolute, but I need position absolute on my elements. Thanks!

```js
$('.share').on("click",function(e){
  if($('.shareMedia').css("bottom")=="54px"){
    $('.shareMedia').css("bottom","0px");
    $('.shareMedia').css("opacity",0);
  }
  else{
     $('.shareMedia').css("bottom","54px");
     $('.shareMedia').css("opacity",1);
  }
});
```

```css
    .shareMedia{
      position: absolute;
      bottom:0;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.40);
      padding: 10px 12px;
      transition:.6s;
      opacity:0;
}

.controls{
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.40);
    padding: 10px 0;
    transition:.6s;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="controls">
        <a href="#" class="play">play</a>
        <a href="#" class="share">share</a>
          <div class="shareMedia">
          <a href="#"><img src="../images/facebook_icon.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="../images/twitter_icon.png"></a>
          <a href="#"><img src="../images/twitter_icon.png"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `position: absolute`, you're essentially covering up the `.play` and `.share` anchors.  You see them only because you have opacity set to 0 on `.shareMedia`.

To fix it, add this CSS:

```
.play, .share {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$('.share').on("click", function(e) {
  if ($('.shareMedia').css("bottom") == "54px") {
    $('.shareMedia').css("bottom", "0px");
    $('.shareMedia').css("opacity", 0);
  } else {
    $('.shareMedia').css("bottom", "54px");
    $('.shareMedia').css("opacity", 1);
  }
});
```

```css
.shareMedia {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .40);
  padding: 10px 12px;
  transition: .6s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.controls {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .40);
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: .6s;
}
.play, .share {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
  <a href="#" class="play">play</a>
  <a href="#" class="share">share</a>
  <div class="shareMedia">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="../images/facebook_icon.png">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="../images/twitter_icon.png">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="../images/twitter_icon.png">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if there is a few weird things, one part of the answer to your question should be the quotes for your opacity value.

```
$('.share').on("click",function(e){
  if($('.shareMedia').css("bottom")=="54px"){
    $('.shareMedia').css("bottom","0px");
    $('.shareMedia').css("opacity","0");
  }
  else{
     $('.shareMedia').css("bottom","54px");
     $('.shareMedia').css("opacity","1");
  }
});
```